# Can't edit sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in Apache on Mac terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface

I'm guessing this should be easy but I can't work anything out.

I'm using terminal on my Mac (latest OS). I'm connecting to a web server and running this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I then see the config file. I can change things, but for the life of my I can't save it. I can see the list of options highlighted at the bottom saying use ^X to exit and I've tried :w! etc. but nothing. The problem seems to be whatever I type is being used as changes to the file, so some how I need to type into terminal but not as an edit to the file.

If I close the terminal then everything is ignored, so that won't work.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if that means anything.

I bet this is easy, but it's really frustrating for me.

Comment: Sudo isn't the issue here

Comment: I was just trying to help. I've found the solution anyway so thanks for the input, I appreciate any advice. I've entered the answer below if it's any use to you.

Comment: Why did somebody make 2 comments and then remove them? Surely that ruins the site.

Comment: not clear question... The title said "Mac terminal" and then you put that you are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^X means to press the control key and X rather than type it in.